# Rest API backend and React frontend is MVP?

Tags: design-patterns, rest, mvc, mvp, react

I'm doing a website that has a React frontend that calls some RESTful API and I would like to know if this is an MVP pattern.

I think that the React application implements the View and the Presenter, while the backend realizes the Model of the website.

I think it's not MVC because the view isn't updated by the model directly, but by how the response is handled.

But I'm not sure the pattern is MVP because the View and the Presenter feel kinda blended (in my code at least).

So my question is basically is my website MVP or not, and if not, what pattern is it implementing if any?

Comment: Communication between a browser and a web server using HTTP isn't a pattern, it's just how the web works.